# How to display multi-part MIME in a browser

Tags: html, mime

I am fetching email messages from a Domino server using a REST service. The response is JSON and contains a number of MIME sections.

[image: Sample MIME]

My current approach is to find the `text/html` section and parse it looking for `img` tags with `src="cid:...`. I then search the other MIME sections for the `cid` and insert the image data. The result is then passed to the browser.

I'm wondering if there is a cleverer way to do this. Is it possible to package the MIME sections in such a way that the browser will do the `cid:` replacements?

**update**
Someone flagged this question as too broad. Would you like to say a bit more? I think the question is quite specific. I want to know if the standard browsers have the capability to look up `cid` references if the MIME parts are appropriately packed into the HTML. This would save me the job of trying to parse HTML myself - a job most browsers are pretty good at!

Comment: Be very, very careful when presenting HTML formatted email in a web browser. Email clients block JavaScript and limit CSS (which can have embedded JS in it). You don't want emails sent to your webmail system to give attackers the ability to run JS under your domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to package the MIME sections in such a way that the browser will do the cid: replacements?

No. You have to do it on the server.

You could replace them with `data:` URIs if you want to keep everything in a single response.